# How to create directional drag by changing velocity of an object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm trying to create directional drag for my game where you drive hovering spaceship (like podracing from starwars). Drag that is already in unity doesn't make any sense for hovering ships, cars etc. because they are usually streamline from the front and aren't from sides. I'm not good at physics but from what I know drag increases the faster you go. I wrote this script, but it doesn't work, the object accelerates on it own once force is added.

```
public Vector3 dragFactor;
private Rigidbody _rb;

void Start() {
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
void FixedUpdate () {
    Vector3 vel = _rb.velocity;
    if(vel.x>0)
        vel.x -= vel.x * dragFactor.x;
    else
        vel.x += vel.x * dragFactor.x;

    if (vel.y > 0)
        vel.y -= vel.y * dragFactor.y;
    else
        vel.y += vel.y * dragFactor.y;

    if (vel.z > 0)
        vel.z -= vel.z * dragFactor.z;
    else
        vel.z += vel.z * dragFactor.z;
    _rb.velocity = vel;
}
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong or what can be changed?

Comment: The docs state you shouldn't manipulate rb.velocity directly. Instead I'd go for rb.AddForce in more or less amounts, depending on what you're trying to achieve. I don't quite get what you mean by directional drag so I can't give an example.

Comment: @Absinthe By directional drag I mean that the drag should be stronger when object is moving for example to the right than when it's moving forward.

Comment: OK, so you'll want to add forces in the required direction, so set up the vectors for positive & negative; if vel.x > your target rb.AddForce(myNegativeXVector), else rb.AddForce(myPositiveXVector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag has to do with surface area. While I cannot give you a coded answer, since I am looking for one myself, at least for angular drag. So it seems like your doing it right. I would say that manually applying drag will also be affected by the objects default drag. So if you have .1 what your seeing in game is 
`vel.x * rb.drag * dragFactor.x`
which is not what you want. So you need to make the rb kinematic and move it manually, so that natural forces do not apply to it.

Additionally you are going to want to multiply by some normalizing variable i.e. `time.fixedDeltaTime`

_vel.x -= vel.x * dragFactor.x * Time.fixedDeltaTime

I found this code that modifies drag dynamically

https://github.com/CoolOppo/Unity-Networking-FPS/blob/master/Assets/Sample%20Assets/Characters%20and%20Vehicles/Aircraft/Scripts/AeroplaneController.cs

Specifically

```
void CalculateDrag ()
{
    // increase the drag based on speed, since a constant drag doesn't seem "Real" (tm) enough
    float extraDrag = rigidbody.velocity.magnitude * dragIncreaseFactor;
    // Air brakes work by directly modifying drag. This part is actually pretty realistic!
    rigidbody.drag = (AirBrakes ? (originalDrag + extraDrag) * airBrakesEffect : originalDrag + extraDrag);
    // Forward speed affects angular drag - at high forward speed, it's much harder for the plane to spin
    rigidbody.angularDrag = originalAngularDrag * ForwardSpeed;
}
```

The above code will help you modify drag at increasing speeds.

** Edit, removed references to isKinematic. Unless you modify position with the velocity, and also apply gravity, then isKinematic is useless. I was hoping that we could use isKinematic to prevent the default drag from applying, it might be best just to make sure that drag on the rigidbody is 0, and that your script sets the custom drag in fixed update.